# .net WebSocketClient's class ConnectAsync is throwing error "Cannot access a disposed object ClientWebSocket'."

Tags: c#, .net, websocket, network-programming

I am trying to continuously listen to server for connection such that whenever the server is available the client will make a connection.

The code sample is as follows:

```
internal async Task ConnectAsync()
{
    try
    {
        if (myWebSocketClient.State != WebSocketState.Open)
        {
            myWebSocketClient.ConnectAsync(InitUri(), CancellationToken.None).Wait(myCancellationToken);
            OnConnectionChange(true, aNumberOfConnectionTries);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception aException)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("An error occured while connecting to server {0}", aException);
        OnConnectionChange(false, aNumberOfConnectionTries);
        aNumberOfConnectionTries++;
        await ConnectAsync();
    }
}
```

> For the first time I get error "Unable to connect to remote server"
>   Which make sense as the server is unavailable. But from next time I
>   get error ""Cannot access a disposed object.\r\nObject name:
>   'System.Net.WebSockets.ClientWebSocket'."

I understand the error but I don't understand why is the client object getting disposed. Is the client object valid for one connection request only.

**I have tried to create a new websocket client object inside connect method, in that case it works fine.**

I want to understand this behavior. Please realize I am new to socket programming.

Comment: If the code is in a "using" block, leaving the using block will dispose the object.

Comment: No, the code is not inside "using" block.

Answer (score 0):

In case of Azure Function listening to service bus queue, you may have to clean and rebuild the Azure Function Project. I did wasted more than hour to understand this. I was debugging the project and closed the app in between.